# Usage of kube-scheduler and kube-controller-manager server ports

Tags: kubernetes

I'm a bit confused about communication model between K8s master components. How does *kube-apiserver*, *kube-controller-manager* and *kube-scheduler* communicate with each other?

According to [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/#cluster-to-master), it seems to me that only *kube-controller-manager* and *kube-scheduler* connects to *kube-apiserver*, but not the other way around. However, I found there were bunch of server-flavored flags provided by both *kube-controller-manager* and *kube-scheduler*, such as `--bind-address` or `--client-ca-file`. So they are both definitely acting as a server too, which I can further confirm using `curl localhost:10251/healthz` and `curl localhost:10252/healthz`.

So the big question mark in my head now is that, what functionalities were provided by *kube-controller-manager*'s and *kube-scheduler*'s server ports? And were they used by *kube-apiserver*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not used by kube-apiserver.

That is health check ports to export current health status and metrics. `--client-ca-file`  is an option for outgoing connections.

Here is a related path of a [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/options/insecure_serving.go) of kube-scheduler.